# Regex select a number in a line

Tags: regex, numbers

I want to select the digits after the `-`, in the following example this digit is `034`:

```
Dossier N° 12090343-034           Pvt du : 24/09/2012 à 17:53
```

I use the following regex:

```
Dossier[^0-9]*\K([0-9]*)(?=-)
```

It match the first number before the `-` in this case `12090343`, but miss the `034`. So, how to match the `034` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `-(\d+)` at the end of the regex

```
Dossier[^0-9]*([0-9]*)-(\d+)
```

Comment: You can drop the `(?=-)` now.

Comment: @AlanMoore: removed lookahead assertion